# NSTextCheckingResult for phone numbers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, validation, ios5

Can someone tell me why this evaluates every time to true?!

The input is: `jkhkjhkj`. It doesn't matter what I type into the `phone` field. It's every time true...

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange (0, [phone length]);    
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [NSTextCheckingResult phoneNumberCheckingResultWithRange:range phoneNumber:phone];
if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber)
{
    return YES;
}
else 
{
    return NO;
}
```

Here is the value of `match`:

```
(NSTextCheckingResult *) $4 = 0x0ab3ba30 <NSPhoneNumberCheckingResult: 0xab3ba30>{0, 8}{jkhkjhkj}
```

I was using RegEx and `NSPredicate` but I've read that since iOS4 it's recommended to use `NSTextCheckingResult` but I can't find any good tutorials or examples on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Recommended" in what scenario? For checking if a certain text is a phone number this method is actually not helpful.

Comment: To elaborate - I can pass "333-3333-3" (not a valid phone number length)  to the accepted answer and it succeeds.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You are using the class incorrectly. `NSTextCheckingResult` is the result of a text checking that is done by `NSDataDetector` or `NSRegularExpression`. Use `NSDataDetector` instead:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber error:&error];

NSRange inputRange = NSMakeRange(0, [phone length]);
NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:phone options:0 range:inputRange];

// no match at all
if ([matches count] == 0) {
    return NO;
}

// found match but we need to check if it matched the whole string
NSTextCheckingResult *result = (NSTextCheckingResult *)[matches objectAtIndex:0];

if ([result resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber && result.range.location == inputRange.location && result.range.length == inputRange.length) {
    // it matched the whole string
    return YES;
}
else {
    // it only matched partial string
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I was just about to write exactly that!

Comment: Thank you so much! Such an example was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: That says 111-111-1111 is a valid phone number

Comment: @JamesO'Brien And?