# Phone number validation using NSDataDetector

Tags: ios, validation, nsdatadetector

How can I validate phone number using NSDataDetector. In my project, the anything higher than 14 text length is also valid but NSDataDetector does not detect it that way.

I am using the code from the following stackoverflow post: [NSTextCheckingResult for phone numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433364/nstextcheckingresult-for-phone-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use `NSDataDetector` its available in for only **[10_7,4_0]**

[image]

So its easy and proper way to validate Phone Number Like bellow way instead of `NSDataDetector`

```
    NSString *string =@"121453315"; 
    NSString *phoneRegex = @"^((\\+)|(00))[0-9]{6,14}$";
    NSPredicate *phoneTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", phoneRegex];
    BOOL phoneValidates = [phoneTest evaluateWithObject:string];
```

Comment: Regular expression seems that this is the only way. I read that it is better to use NSDataDetector because it checks phone number based on country but it seems in my case where the client wants to allow more than 14 character, I will have to use RegEx. Thanks. @Nitin

Comment: @Joy not getting why you unAccept again after accepting answer.. anyWAay its ok

Comment: I am sorry but I first clicked on answer accepted without testing. But when I tested, it seems to be not validating the phone number which was being validated OK while using NSDataDetector.

Comment: ther you need to set regix string as par you input and as pr you need

Answer (score 0):

Use NSDataDetector for regular phone numbers, and add a special regex matching only 14-digit+ phone numbers that your app needs to add the missing results. For shorter phone numbers, NSDataDetector will be far more accurate that any regex you may write...